# Sorting through list and storing distinct values

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm using pandas to read data that looks like this:

```
 0   overcast
 1   overcast
 2   overcast
 3   overcast
 4      rainy
 5      rainy
 6      rainy
 7      rainy
 8      rainy
 9      sunny
 10     sunny
 11     sunny
 12     sunny
 13     sunny
```

And I wish to store overcast (first entry) as a variable, and then iterate through the list until there is a contrasting variable, and store that one also. This should assign any other contrasting variables along the way until until the end of the list.

I'm having a hard time figuring out the best way to do this or maybe there is something in pandas that does this for me that I'm missing?

Edit: So I want to start at position [0,0] to get 'overcast' and make that variable *a* and for it to run down the list until it hits 'rainy' by that point it stores it in *b*, then 'sunny' into *c*, etc. but I want to understand how to make it robust so that no matter the amount of labels, it'll store it. Not hilbert's hotel big but say a couple hundred.

Comment: Please add the stacktrace and code. You may also have a look at [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the question.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Also, variables can't be named with numbers. I'd suggest creating a list or dict to store all of the  'contrasting variables'.

Comment: My problem is the algorithm I should use to iterate through the list of values until it has been through the entire list and stored each different value as a separate node or variable. 

The logic is the part I'm having a hard time with. I know I need a key, current comparison, and then a way to store each new variable in a column it finds as a separate object, no matter the amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas offers the `unique()` method to identify distinct values of a column.  Then you can transpose to get into a row.

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.unique()).T          # T = transpose()

          0      1      2
0  overcast  rainy  sunny
```

Or do the following to rename the columns.  (I can't tell if you want them as row names or row values.)

```
>>> df2.columns = df.unique()

   overcast  rainy  sunny
0  overcast  rainy  sunny
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you've helped me move on in this project.